# unrecognised expression in jquery selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I use the following jquery selector :

> var obj = $('td"[headers=ORDER_ID]" a');

but firebug shows the following error :

> Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: td"[headers=ORDER_ID]" a

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Use `$('td[headers="ORDER_ID"] a')`

Comment: Or just $("td[headers=ORDER_ID] a") (but I prefer @Tushar 's personally).  If 'ORDER_ID' is a variable and you want quotes, then `$('td[headers="' + ORDER_ID + '"] a')` (note use of `'` and `"` which is hard to see here)

Comment: thanks Tushar it now works ! solved